# Avoid white space when dragging/scrolling an image in Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, scroll, drag

So I have an image (1020x736) inside a canvas (700x600) and I am trying to scroll/drag the image around so that I can see the rest of it except I don't want to see the white space when I reach the image bounds while I am dragging the image.

Here's a sample of my problem

[image]

The black borders indicates the canvas' borders.

Here's my code so far

```
var dragging = false;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var lastX;
var lastY;
var translated = 0;

canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
  var evt = e || event;
  dragging = true;
  lastX = evt.offsetX;
  lastY = evt.offsetY;
}

window.onmousemove = function(e){
  var evt = e || event;
  if(dragging){
    var deltaX = evt.offsetX - lastX;
    var deltaY = evt.offsetY - lastY;
    context.translate(deltaX,deltaY);
    lastX = evt.offsetX;
    lastY = evt.offsetY;
    draw();
  }
}

function draw(){
  var image = document.getElementById('img1');

  context.drawImage(image,0,0);
}

canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
  dragging = false;
}


window.onload = draw;
```

Answer (score 0):

Drawing from the top left corner to keep the image from going to far into the canvas

```
// canvas is the canvas
// img is the image you are drawing;
// posX and posY are the location (top left) that the image has been dragged to 
x = Math.max( -(img.width - canvas.width), Math.min(0, posX));
y = Math.max( -(img.height - canvas.height), Math.min(0, posY));

ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I assume this should be in the draw function right? I tried that and it didn't change anything. deltaX and deltaY in my code refer to posX and posY in your code.

Comment: You will have to track the absolute position of the dragging image, or you can not know if it is out of bounds.